# how push some elements of an array to another

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax, highcharts

I am trying to create a chart of the exchange rate. In the array I am writing data about the exchange rate and I want to move this data to the chart.
And i dont know how to do it.

This is array `["25.09", "25.03", "24.88"]
0: "25.09"
1: "25.03"
2: "24.88"`
[Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uuR7.png)

```js
var dataArr = [];
async function currency(e) {
 chartData.series[0].data = [];
var sdate=startdate.value.split("-").join("");
var edate=enddate.value.split("-").join("");
 for (var i = Number(sdate); i <= Number(edate); i++){
 await delay(2000)
 let url=`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?valcode=${currenc.value}&date=${i}&json`;
let response= await fetch(url);
let data =await response.json();
var itemObj={
 rate:data[0].rate,
 exchangedate:data[0].exchangedate
 };
 dataArr.push(itemObj.rate.toFixed(2)); //here push elements to array

 
}
console.log(dataArr);
}
```

And here I need to move the values, i.e. to schedule

```js
var chartData = {
    title: {
        text: 'NBU Currency'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Exchange rate'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: '',
        data:[] // OVER HERE!!
    }],
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            }
        }]
    }
}

Highcharts.chart('container', chartData);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. you need to select the items from the first array. You can reference them by using their position/index. `let pushItem = dataArr[0];`
2. then just use the push method to add it to the second array. `dataArr2.push(pushItem);`

your second array (dataArr2) will now contain the item.

You can also store objects or other arrays this way. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the issue here exactly, yet check this example:

```
var data = ["25.09", "25.03", "24.88"];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: data.map(elem => +elem)
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pfd205cn/